Unbalanced hashed HAProxy balancing
I have a simple HAProxy balancing based on a header:
backend backend_nodes
  balance hdr(x-some-header)
  # hash-type consistent sdbm avalanche
  server r-0 s-0.svc.cluster.local:80 weight 1 check
  server r-1 s-1.svc.cluster.local:80 weight 1 check
  server r-2 s-2.svc.cluster.local:80 weight 1 check

And currently we have these clients with x-some-header values of:
34b2183e-230e-4ff5-8655-424c411f0b93
5a7e3770-95ad-405d-86b9-9a2f85e1f2c6
b3ae3c47-85b0-4dcb-a1bf-6f38efabec5b
ecfdc8af-16a2-442c-b855-135b6aef28d9

0b375e76-24a0-463b-97c3-95e85036d395
357f76cb-a9e4-46ef-a849-f06acf68f5a5
7d8adf1f-df74-4bf1-8a8d-c1befae1cdc1
99902db2-72dd-4c6e-a720-516e01acee80

First half of those 8 clients go to r-1 and the other half go to r-2.
I have tried with consistent hashing as you can see from the commented line, but the result is the same.
Sometimes it works, but I expect any hashing to result in at least one of those 8 clients going to the 3rd server.
PS: The status of all servers is constantly healthy and there are no errors or anything in the haproxy logs.
Any ideas?
